# Rails 4 Rspec 2.14 controller test - string vs. integer in CREATE/UPDATE controller tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

Below are CREATE and UPDATE controller tests in rspec - I'm testing the creating/updating of an invoice object with nested invoice item attributes.  My question is why does the UPDATE test require me to specify integers as "strings" whereas the CREATE test does not?  If I don't do this I get an expected/got error.

**Controller CREATE test**

```
describe "PUT/POST actions" do

    describe "POST create" do 

      before do

        @invoice_item_attrs = {"0"=>{"description"=>"something", "line_total"=>1.0, "unit_cost" => 1.0, "quantity" => 1.0, "item" => "item", "invoice_id" => 1, "_destroy"=>false}}

        @client = FactoryGirl.build(:client, user: @user)

        @valid_invoice_params = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(paid: true, date_sent: "Wed, 18 Dec 2013 00:19:00 +0000", client_id: "#{@client.id}", user_id: "#{@user.id}", invoice_items_attributes: @invoice_item_attrs)

      end

      describe "with valid params" do

        it "creates a new Invoice" do

          expect {

            post :create, {:invoice => @valid_invoice_params, :user_id => @user.id}

          }.to change(Invoice, :count).by(1)

        end
```

**Controller UPDATE test**

describe "PUT update" do

```
  before do

    @invoice = FactoryGirl.create(:invoice, user: @user)

    @client = FactoryGirl.build(:client, user: @user)

    @invoice_item_attrs = {"0"=>{"description"=>"something", "line_total"=>"1.0", "unit_cost" => "1.0", "quantity" => "1.0", "item" => "item", "invoice_id" => "1", "_destroy"=>false}}

    @valid_invoice_params = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(paid: true, date_sent: "Wed, 18 Dec 2021 00:19:00 +0000", client_id: "#{@client.id}", user_id: "#{@user.id}", invoice_items_attributes: @invoice_item_attrs)

  end

  describe "with valid params" do

    it "updates the requested invoice" do

      # Assuming there are no other invoices in the database, this

      # specifies that the Invoice created on the previous line

      # receives the :update_attributes message with whatever params are

      # submitted in the request.

      Invoice.any_instance.should_receive(:update).with(@valid_invoice_params)

      put :update, {:id => @invoice.to_param, :invoice => @valid_invoice_params, user_id: @user.to_param}

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify strings in the `update` case because you're setting an expectation with RSpec about what the `Invoice` instance will receive (i.e. via `with(...)` and a string is different than integer. Apparently the controller code you have turns integers into strings in that situation.

You can use either in the `create` case because you're not setting any parameter expectations there, just passing a hash to some production code (i.e. via `post ...`) which will gladly accept either.